# How to integrate inspinia into rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, inspinia

My problem is with the `inspinia.js` file in rails 6.

I have the file `inspinia.js` and `application.js` in :-

> app / javascript / pack

Try to integrate it in the following ways:

```
import 'inspinia'
require ("inspinia")
```

and in some other ways that didn't help me either.
If someone has already done it or knows how to do it, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you said that you've put it in the `app/javascript/packs` directory.
All you have to do is require it in `application.js` like:

```rb
require ("packs/inspinia");
```

You can also include it in the the `index.html.erb` like:

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'inspinia', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'  %>
```